# WPF UI Freezing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am trying to update 2 labels and 2 progress bars on the UI.
However it does not work, the form just freezes and nothing happens until the saving is over.
In windows forms I am used to using Invoke and making it update. How can I achieve updating in WPF?

Thanks!

```
public void EncryptFiles(string saveFileLocation, string saveFileTitle, string saveFileExtension)
{

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {


        zip.Password = passwordField1.Password;
        zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
        foreach (File file in dataStorage.listOfFiles)
        {

            zip.AddFile(file.fileLocation, String.Empty);
        }
        zip.SaveProgress += SaveProgress;


        zip.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(saveFileLocation, saveFileTitle + saveFileExtension));

    }

}


public void SaveProgress(object sender, SaveProgressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Started)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Begin Saving: " + e.ArchiveName);
    }
    else if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_BeforeWriteEntry)
    {

        labelCompressionStatus.Content = "Writing: " + e.CurrentEntry.FileName + " (" + (e.EntriesSaved + 1) + "/" + e.EntriesTotal + ")";
        labelFilename.Content= "Filename:" + e.CurrentEntry.FileName;
        progressBar2.Maximum = e.EntriesTotal;
        progressBar2.Value = e.EntriesSaved + 1;


    }
    else if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_EntryBytesRead)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)((e.BytesTransferred * 100) / e.TotalBytesToTransfer);  
    }
    else if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Completed)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Done: " + e.ArchiveName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put ProgressBar task on a Worker Thread, as explained in this sample: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/

Comment: This answer may be USEFUL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253088/updating-gui-wpf-using-a-different-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** My answer only applies if you're running your unzip operation on a thread that is different than the UI thread (does not have to be a background worker). Otherwise, furkle's answer is what you want.

Check out the WPF [dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/how-can-i-use-the-dispatcher-invoke-in-wpf-change-controls-from-non-main-thread). It's designed for this usage case, and is roughly analogous to `Control.Invoke()` in Winforms.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { 
 // code here for updating GUI
 }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Found this and it works for me, thanks everyonne

Comment: If this worked for you, you should accept Xcelled194's answer - he told you to do that nearly half an hour ago.

Comment: Combined with background worker, this worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Unless you execute your code in a separate thread, the UI will not update until you complete your method. Changing the value of `progressBar1` won't end up mattering, because the changes won't be visible until after all the work completes. The easiest way to do this would probably be to assign the work of `EncryptFiles` to a BackgroundWorker:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
bw.DoWork += EncryptFiles;
bw.ProgressChanged += ReportEncryptSaveProgress;
```

Then, keep reference to `bw` and call `bw.ReportProgress()` each time the task is updated, passing the percentage of completion to the method. Given that `ReportProgress` occurs on the UI thread, you should put your updates to your `ProgressBars` therein, and the user should see the progress of saving.

Note that I'm not 100% sure how you'd want to move your work into the BackgroundWorker - I'm not positive I know how the `ZipFile` object's events work, so you might have to work with it a bit. It might end up easier to make the `BackgroundWorker` a field of your class rather than trying to pass it to `SaveProgress`, given that I'm assuming you can't alter `SaveProgress`'s method signature.

You could accomplish the UI updates by using the Dispatcher, but your UI will still end up totally locked for the entirety of the operation, and that's generally good to avoid.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I assumed he was already running this on a separate thread, since he said he's done similar stuff in WinForms.

Comment: @Xcelled194 That's a bit of an assumption on my part, but it doesn't seem like he's on a different thread. Otherwise I expect he'd be asking about `InvalidCrossThreadAccess` and not why his UI just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Perhaps he got that error and resolved it? Though I don't know how you could resolve it *without* the Dispatcher... I guess we'll have to wait and see what the OP says.