# File transfer details binding continuously until file transfered in window using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winscp, winscp-net

I have created project to transferring file from client to server. I have done file transferred and got file transferred details such as file name (something.avi) and percentage (10%) of file transferred like below, Whenever I'm transferring a file, I'm using below event handler for knowing the file transferred details.

```
private static void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
{
    // New line for every new file
    if ((_lastFileName != null) && (_lastFileName != e.FileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Print transfer progress
    Console.Write("\r{0} ({1:P0})", e.FileName, e.FileProgress);

    // Remember a name of the last file reported
    _lastFileName = e.FileName;
}
private static string _lastFileName;
```

I need to bind this transferred details in window. I have done binding while file transferred. But I need how to bind every second file transferred details in window using WPF. Because I need to show progress of file transferring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WinSCP .NET assembly [`Session.FileTransferProgress`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress) event is triggered continuously.

So all you need to do, is to update your control in the event handler.

As the event is triggered on a background thread, you need to use [`Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke). See [Updating GUI (WPF) using a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4253088/850848).

For an example WinForms code, see WinSCP article [Displaying FTP/SFTP transfer progress on WinForms ProgressBar](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_winforms_progressbar). With WPF, the code will be very similar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..nice one..Worked for me..@Martin Prikryl

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution with help of @Martin Prikryl..Please find below code

```
progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value = (int)(e.FileProgress * 100), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

This is for progress bar moving with file trasnfer progress..I will post once done the display progress in percentage.

progressBar is name of Xaml element in wpf.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the code for display file transfer progress with percentage. Please find the below both Xaml and c# code for wpf window.

Xaml for percentage display in window using wpf.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="percentage" Text=""  Height="27" Width="50" FontSize="20"/>
```

C# code for binding the file transfer progress in percentage.

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
{
   this.percentage.Text = ((e.FileProgress * 100).ToString() + "%");
}));
```

Comment: Please edit your other question to add this information. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.