# Cancel file transfers while transferring file to destination

Tags: c#, wpf, winscp, winscp-net

I have used Winscp for file transferring and got details file transfer progress like below link,

[File transfer details binding continuously until file transfered in window using WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364376/file-transfer-details-binding-continuously-until-file-transfered-in-window-using/43383751#43383751)

and transfer code link below

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

But i need to cancel file transferring. Please give your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding the only way to achieve this is to abort the current session.

link: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_abort

Comment: How to define Abort method? @William Cross

Comment: if you follow the getfiles example here: 
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles - you will see that the getfiles method is invoked inside a new session (in this example, named session). If you were to abort the session that getfiles is contained within you would interrupt the file transfer.

Comment: I have canceled file transferring with help of Abort();..Thanks @William Cross

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FileTransferProgressEventArgs.Cancel`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_filetransferprogresseventargs#cancel):

```
bool cancel = false; // set to true to cancel the transfer

session.FileTransferProgress +=
    (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    };

session.PutFiles(localPath, remotePath).Check();
```