# Set variable or reference to an already open form

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables, backgroundworker

I am new to c# and am having trouble getting my head around  declaring variables.

I have a lengthyprocess which I have sent to a background worker. Whilst the lengthyprocess does its thing, a form displays telling the user to wait. When the lengthyprocess finishes I want the wait form to close.

How do I refer to the already existing instance of the wait form so that I can close it in the closing process of the background worker? The close process is in a different private void to the one that the wait form was opened in, and I can't seem to declare the form outside of a private void.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: private void is a scope and a type (or lack there of). Do you mean within 2 different classes? Can you provide a bit of code to clarify?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the response, I just got home from work, will have to post code tomorrow.

Comment: At you class level you just declare the variable.

Comment: That's what I tried doing. I tried declaring the wait form as var, form and window, and each one came up with a red line underneath it and an error saying it was not possible to declare such an object at the class level...

Comment: See my answer.  You are not using the correct type.

Comment: Thanks balam, that looks like exactly what I am looking for. I will test it out at work tomorrow and let you know how it went. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class in .NET, it has a [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event. Just register an event handler to close the form.

**EDIT**

Best bet is to read the [MSDN documentation for BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Note that there are 2 examples provided, the second is better as the first does not event registration code that is helpful to understanding. AND way at the bottom of the page is a commenter-provided example that is pretty good (*BGW Nuances including Sample with ProgressBar*).

Maybe this outline is helpful:

1. Your MainForm instantiates a WaitForm (a [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) ?)
2. Your MainForm instantiates a BackgroundWorker
3. Your MainForm has appropriate event handlers for BackgroundWorker and ProgressBar events.
4. A ProgressBar does not have to be explicitly closed.

Comment: The runworkercompleted handle is already set up and working, within that I want to refer to the already open waitform so that I can close this. I'm not sure how to set up this reference, as the wait form us opened in a separate type.

Comment: But how does RunWorkerComplete get a reference to that form?

Answer (score 0):

You want your callback to hit some code that "Invokes" your UI changes.

[C# How does a background thread tell a UI thread that it has finished doing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684341/c-sharp-how-does-a-background-thread-tell-a-ui-thread-that-it-has-finished-doing)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the form in the class but out of a method:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

But show it when needed: (-in a method)

```
frm2.Show();
```

(My answer is for winforms. I now noticed you're referring to wpf. I don't know if it works the same.)

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do bit in wpf.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and [how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). There is all information that you're interested in.

Comment: The runworkercompleted handle is already set up and working, within that I want to refer to the already open waitform so that I can close this. I'm not sure how to set up this reference, as the wait form us opened in a separate type.

Answer (score 0):

You can, do may be something like this, if I correct understood your intentions:

```
public class FormWait
{
     private static FormWait frm = new FormWait();

     public static void ShowForm(string message)
     {
         Show(message);
     }

     public static void Close()
     {
         Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                  if(!frm.Visible)
                      return;

                  frm .Close();
            }));


     }

     private void Show(string str)
     {
       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                 if(frm.Visible)
                    frm.Close();
                 lblMessage.Text = message; // assume that there is a label on the Form to show the message

                  frm .Show();
            }));


     }

   }
```

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post you code for the wait form so I kind of have to guess.  In short you need a private variable at the class level to close.   This is tested code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    NavigationWindow winWait;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnShow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (winWait != null) return; 
        winWait = new NavigationWindow();
        winWait.Content = new PageWait();
        winWait.Show();
    }

    private void btnHide(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (winWait != null) winWait.Close();
    }

}
```

If you want to have multiple "wait" forms then you would need to get a little fancier.  You would not have the Navigation variable at the class rather create it and pass it to the background so it can be passed back to the call back.  And you need to deal with != null but not active.

Answer (score 0):

For those it may concern:

Using BalamBalam's very helpful code I managed to get this working as below:

```
           class DatabaseUpdater
{ 
// Declare the background worker and WaitForm at Class Level
static BackgroundWorker bw;
public static Form WaitForm;


public static void DelegateWorkStuff()
{

    // Set up the background process and show WaitForm in here        

    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    WaitForm = new WaitForm();
    WaitForm.Show();

    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
 }

   static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Run the lenghty code/processes in here
    }

   static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
        //Close the Waitform thus
        WaitForm.Close();
   }
```